# If and then query

Tags: microsoft-excel, query

I want to populate the cell J4 based on the table value (see attached image)

```
If cell IA = WDDS the populate with table WDDS value 6:00
If cell IA = WDAS the populate with table WDAS value 12:00
If cell IA = WDNS the populate with table WDNS value 20:00
If cell IA = WEDS the populate with table WEDS value 8:00
If cell IA = WENS the populate with table WENS value 20:00
If cell IA = SAL the populate with table SAL value 8:00
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Excel's `IF` formula has the following syntax:

```
=IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

You can embed one IF inside of another, which for this specific example gives the following formula in cell `J4`:

```
=IF(I4=F4,E4,IF(I4=F5,E5,IF(I4=F6,E6,IF(I4=F7,E7,IF(I4=F8,E8,IF(I4=F9,E9,""))))))
```

This chains multiple if-then-else blocks together, and does a simple text comparison between `I4` and `F4:F9` to determine which cell in `E4:E9` to use.

Just to look at the first part:

```
=IF(I4=F4,E4,IF(...
```

- `I4=F4`: logical test, determines if the contents of cells `I4` and `F4` are equal.
- `E4`: value if true, the contents of `E4` will be displayed if the logical test `I4=F4` is true.
- `IF(`...: value if false, in this case another IF that checks another value.

Unfortunately it is a bit unwieldy, and becomes more so as more values are added.